# onsen-ui grid-menu template is missing

Tags: onsen-ui

I am looking for the Grid-Menu pattern, it is not present any more on: http://components.onsen.io/patterns

It used to be there as it can be seen in here:
http://www.aiship.jp/knowhow/archives/17829

Is it still supported?
Where can I find the old pattern for a quick start?

Thanks!

Comment: I just opened an issue to add this kind of pattern. I cannot find it right now but you can use the CSS in this codepen for it: http://codepen.io/hideokamoto/pen/znjhq

Comment: Great! that is really helps!
Thanks